# tinymce 4 init button

Tags: javascript, button, initialization, tinymce-4

Question about tinymce 4-th version.
when I add a button

```
editor.addButton('cut_tag', {
                type: 'button',
                text: '<cut>',
                name: 'cut_tag',
                id: 'cut_tag',
                icon: false,
                tooltip: 'Вставить cut',
                onclick: function(e){
                    editor.insertContent('[cut]');
                    this.disabled(true);
                    editor.cut_tag_button = this; // hack - store object in var to get object from var later
                }
            });
```

And I want to execute some code when initializing button, I tried 'oninit', 'oncreate', 'setup', etc. but no effect. Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the onclick event outside the add button object.

```
editor.addButton(...);
editor.on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Insert logic here');
});
```

The syntax has also changed a little.  This [TinyMCE Migration Guide](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial%3aMigration_guide_from_3.x) might help explain more.